# Single Anaconda Environment On Multiple Machines

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda

Is it possible to share one environment between multiple machines? I regularly switch between machines, and would like to use a single anaconda environment.

Comment: You like `conda create --file=...`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you have file access between the machine's you can load the remote env on the host machine with annaconda on the local machine. Or you can copy the annaconda env folder and manually transfer it between machines.

For detailed instructions refer to:
https://conda.io/docs/test-drive.html#managing-environments

Comment: Can you add some specifics? Where is the env located? How can I load it on the other machine, especially if I'm going PC to Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a scenario via the `.condarc` file and Anaconda PowerShell:

Suppose you are on `machine_01`, and you have an environment `myenv` on network-shared folder `L:\python_projects\envs`

To access the same environment `myenv` from another machine (`machine_02`) you have to do the following on machine_02:

1-  Download the latest Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/ and finish installation on recommended path under your username (`C:\Users\yourname\Anaconda3`)

Note: you don’t need the admin rights because the installation will be under your username.

2-  Check if Anaconda added to your path. Open Anaconda PowerShell from windows start menu and enter this command `conda --version`

The result look like: `conda 4.12.0`. Which means Anaconda added to path and everything is fine.

If you get a command not recognized error, type this command's `where conda` to find where is conda installed then add the conda path to your PATH in Windows Environment Variables.

3-  Enter this command `conda info --envs` into your Anaconda PowerShell to check the available environments. You will find the base environment only like this:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\yourname\Anaconda3
```

4-  Open the `.condarc file` under `C:\Users\yourname` on `machine_02` and add the path of environment's shared folder at the end of the file:

```
envs_dirs:
  - L:\python_projects\envs
```

5-  Save the `.condarc file` and type this command again `conda info --envs` to list the available environments. You will find the new environment with the base environment:

```
# conda environments:
#
base              * C:\Users\yourname\Anaconda3
myenv               L:\ python_projects\envs\myenv
```